# Obtención de datos de Promise {<pending>}

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un problemas con una función para obtener datos de una API, la función está ubicada en el archivo `api.js`, el resultado de esa respuesta la tengo que pasar al Compente `Customers.js` y el resultado de dicha función es `Promise {<pending>}` como haría para obtener los datos correcto para la obtención de los datos dentro de mi Componente `Clientes.js`? la función es la siguiente:

```
  export const getCustomers = async () => {
 
  let URL = 'https://myapi.test/';
  let data = {
    "page": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 10,
    "sortField": "completeName",
    "reverse": false
  }
  
  const response = await axios.post(URL, data, config).then(r =>{
    return r.data.items;
  });
  
  return response;
};
```

planteo otra incógnita, cual sería el Hook adecuado a usar?, mi componente `Customer.js`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getCustomers } from "./../../providers/api";

function Customers() {

   return (<><div className="container"></div></>);

}

export default Customers;
```

Comment: Si la funcion la usas como: `const response = await getCustomers()` el resultado no debería ser un `Promise {<pending>}`

Comment: Créeme que ese es el resultado que me da

Comment: Puedes compartir el código de cómo la estás usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El motivo es que esas generando un then a tu respuestas y ya es una promesa, estas haciendo doble promesa con ese then. Intenta con esto.

```
export const getCustomers = async () => { 
  let URL = 'https://myapi.test/';
  let data = {
    "page": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 10,
    "sortField": "completeName",
    "reverse": false
  }
  
  const { data }= await axios.post(URL, data, config);
  
  return data.items;
};
```